# Getting values from pair to HashMap in Java

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have a `Map<Pair<String, String>, Integer>` like this :

```
Pair.left Pair.right Integer
1          A          10
1          B          20
2          C          30
```

Now, If i pass the Pair.left value like 1 then i should get the Pair.right and that Integer in a map like :

```
Map<String, Integer> :
A  10
B  20

If i pass 2, 
then 
C 30
```

So, I try this :

```
public Map<String, Integr> foo(Map<Pair<String, String>, Integer> input, String LeftValue)
{
    Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap();
    Set<Pair<String, String>> inputKeysets = input.keySet();

    //Now, I am thinking i will loop through the inputKeysets and see if the getLeft() matches the LeftValue, if it does then i will take the getRight() and store in a new Set
    //Then i will have LeftValue and RightValue and then will compare again from the input and get the Integer value

}
```

Is there any easy way from lambda to do this ?

Comment: If you are interested in values based only on `Pair.left`, then why are you using the entire `Pair` class as your map key?

Comment: Because based on Pair.left i will know what to pass and it is already used at few other places. I need mapping of pair.left and pair.right at few places.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
public Map<String, Integer> foo(Map<Pair<String, String>, Integer> input, String leftValue) {
    return input.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getKey().left.equals(leftValue))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey().right, e -> e.getValue()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow up with a grouping operation using a mapping downstream such as:

```
public Map<String, List<Pair<String, Integer>>> groupedByLeft(Map<Pair<String, String>, Integer> input) {
    return input.entrySet().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getKey().getLeft(),
                             Collectors.mapping(e -> Pair.of(e.getKey().getRight(), e.getValue()),
                                  Collectors.toList())));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Idea is to build the temporary data structure that holds left -> Map(right, integer) and return a map with given left value.

```
public Map<String, Integer> foo(Map<Pair<String, String>, Integer> input, String LeftValue) {
    Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap();
    Set<Pair<String, String>> inputKeysets = input.keySet();

    Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> tempDS = new HashMap<>();
    for (Pair<String, String> pair : inputKeysets) {
        String left = pair.getKey();
        String right = pair.getValue();
        int value = input.get(pair);
        if (tempDS.containsKey(left)) {
            tempDS.get(left).put(right, value);
        } else {
            Map<String, Integer> temp = new HashMap<>();
            temp.put(right, value);
            tempDS.put(left, temp);
        }
    }
    return tempDS.get(LeftValue);
}
```